# Display an alert with message according to the radio button

Tags: javascript, html, button, radio-button

```
<html>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
for(k=1; k<=3; k++)
    checkVal(document.getElementsByName("radio"+k))     

}

 function checkVal(selector){
 for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {       
    if (selector[i].checked) {
        switch (selector[i].value){
            case '1' :
                alert("You can't go")
                break;
            case '2' :
                alert("You can go")
                break;
            }

        break;  

    }
   }
  }
</script>

   <div>
    <p>QUESTION 1</p></br></br>
    <input name="radio1" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
    <input name="radio1" value="2" type="radio">No</br></br>

    <p>QUESTION 2</p></br></br>
    <input name="radio2" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
    <input name="radio2" value="2" type="radio">No</br></br>

    <p>QUESTION 3</p></br></br>
    <input name="radio3" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
    <input name="radio3" value="2" type="radio">No</br></br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send" />
  </div>
</html>
```

Hello i found this script on this site but i need to edit it.
I don't know what i've to do because i don't know Javascript so i need your help...
This function give me three alert but i need that if the user selects only one "yes" the function has to give to the user the `alert("you can't go")`.
The `alert("you can go")` has to be shown only if the user selects all yes.
Who can help me? <3

Answer (score 1):

try this javascript code :

```
    <script>
function myFunction()
{
var count = 0;
for(k=1; k<=3; k++){
 count += checkVal(document.getElementsByName("radio"+k))   
}
if(count==3){
        alert("You can go");
   }else{
        alert("You can't go")
  }
}

 function checkVal(selector){
 var count = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {       
    if (selector[i].checked) {
        if(selector[i].value == '1'){
            count = 1;
        }
    }
 }
    return count ; 

  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Note**: This snippet using `jQuery`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            isValid = false;
        }
    });

    if (!isValid) {
        alert("You can't go");
    }
    else {
        alert('Go well');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>QUESTION 1</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio1" value="1" checked="" type="radio" />Yes<br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio1" value="2" type="radio" />No<br />
    <br />
    <p>QUESTION 2</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio2" value="1" checked="" type="radio" />Yes<br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio2" value="2" type="radio" />No<br />
    <br />
    <p>QUESTION 3</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio3" value="1" checked="" type="radio" />Yes<br />
    <br />
    <input name="radio3" value="2" type="radio" />No<br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send" />
</div>
```